Get real time Fingerprint log from zkteco speedface v5l to c# winform
I attempted to integrate my Winform application with real-time attendance.
I have used the zkemkeeper class. devices connected.
can read other data. but cannot get real-time log.
    private void EnableRealTimeTracking()
{
   
    
    if (isConnected)
    {
        
         
        zkem.OnAttTransactionEx += RealTimeLogHandler;
        MessageBox.Show("Real-time tracking enabled.");
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please connect to the device first.");
    }
}



    private void RealTimeLogHandler(
string EnrollNumber,   
int IsInValid,        
int AttState,          
int VerifyMethod,     
int Year,              
int Month,             
int Day,               
int Hour,             
int Minute,          
int Second,           
int WorkCode)         
   {
       // Construct the date-time string for the transaction
       string dateTime = $"{Year}-{Month:D2}-{Day:D2} {Hour:D2}:{Minute:D2}:{Second:D2}";

       // Determine the verification method (e.g., Fingerprint or other)
       string verifyMethodStr = VerifyMethod == 1 ? "Fingerprint" : "Other";

       // Determine the attendance state (In or Out)
       string attStateStr = AttState == 1 ? "In" : "Out";

       // If the transaction is valid, process it
       if (IsInValid == 1)
       {
           // Update the DataTable with the attendance information
           // We are using Invoke to ensure thread-safety when updating the UI from the event handler
           Invoke(new Action(() =>
           {
               // Add a new row to the DataTable for the attendance log
               attendanceTable.Rows.Add(EnrollNumber, verifyMethodStr, dateTime, WorkCode);
           }));
       }
       else
       {
           // Optionally, handle invalid transactions, if needed
           // For example, you can log it or alert the user
           Console.WriteLine("Invalid attendance transaction for user: " + EnrollNumber);
       }
   }

I need that real-time log data, so please let me know how to invoke it or if you have any suggestions.
